# Laravel: A field that lookup another field from different table

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-backpack

I use Backpack for Laravel.

I know that to add a field, we can use:

```
CRUD::addField(['name'=>..])
```

But, I don't know how to add a field that lookup another field input from different table to show a lookup value.

Please look at the illustration below.

Thanks.

[image: Lookup Field]

**Edit**:

I found a temporary solution to this, but not effective.

Reference: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-how-to#add-a-select2-field-that-depends-on-another-field

With select2_from_ajax you still have to select the option (even its just one option left), meanwhile what I really want is its automatically select that one option.

Comment: you can use relationship or a join. what's not working here??

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you want user name from users table to display base on user_id?

Comment: @SokChanty yes!

Comment: @zahidhasanemon hmm, how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on what you need to do. You can use relationship field and show a select with the list of user. If you really wanna do it like this. You can probably make an ajax request to show it. In that case you ll need to use a custom view for the edit or the create view.

Comment: can you give me an example how to do it, please? if i use relationship with select field i got the value of id not the user_id